# How do I search just the children of an XDocument, rather than all of its descendants?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I can't seem to find anything other than `XDocument.Descendants ()` in the documentation. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: how do differentiate descendants and children. It is an Element or an Attribute you can get to for every descendant or Children

Comment: @Asad I'm not sure I understand your question. Using the analogy of a real family, your descendants would include your children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc. Your children are just your children.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

what you're looking for might be `XDocument.Elements()`. [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.elements.aspx).